# How to find Level of element from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array  which has id and parent_id like this

```
 $element=new array(
          [0]=>array(1,0), --------level     1
           [1]=>array(2,0), -------level     1
           [2]=>array(3,1), ------level      2
           [3]=>array(4,1),  ------level     2
           [4]=>array(5,1), ------level      2
           [5]=>array(6,2), ------level      2
           [6]=>array(7,3), ------level      3
           [7]=>array(8,2), ------level      2
           [8]=>array(9,3), ------level      3
           [9]=>array(10,6), ------level     3
           [10]=>array(11,6), ------level     3

 );
```

this is my array, in inner array first element is id of the array and second element  is id of parent element.

now i want to find level of each element from root.

assume zero (0) is root element.

Comment: I'm 100% not following the logic. Can you try explaining the logic on what determines the "level" again?

Comment: This is probably a RDBMS way of representing a tree in a table. Level seems to be the distance from root node.

Comment: If that's true, see http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: If it is just PHP then arrays are just wrong tool for the job. If you have a tree use a tree data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive approach. I'm assuming that the item at index `N` in the outer array always has id `N+1`. If not, you'll first have to search for the item with the matching id, but otherwise the rest of the logic should be the same.

```
<?php
function findLevel($id) {
    $item = $element[$id-1];    //If my assumption (above) is incorrect,
                                // you'll need to replace this with an appropriate
                                // search function, which could be as simple as
                                // a loop through the array.
    $parent = $item[1];
    if ($parent == 0) {
        //Parent is root. Assuming root is level 0, then
        // this item is level 1.
        return 1;
    }
    return 1 + findLevel($parent);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$parent_id = n;
$level = 0;
while($parent_id != 0){
   $inner_array = $element[$parent_id];
   $parent_id = $inner_array[1];
   $level ++;
}
```

Let's try this, you initially set $parent_id to the index of the $element array you want to know the level.
Make sure each level can be calculated